# libxslt: xml to html text encoding issue iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xslt, libxslt

I am using xslt framework to convert xml to html for iOS project.
I am sending the encoded xml to the xslt framework. But the output it gives is not encoded. So when i try to parse the html, i am getting the parser error.

```
NSString *xml = @"<div>a&lt;b</div>" // not exact this but its similar in encoding
NSData *xmlMem = [xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString* styleSheetPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName  ofType:fileExtension];
xmlDocPtr doc, res;
xsltStylesheetPtr sty;
xmlSubstituteEntitiesDefault(1);
xmlLoadExtDtdDefaultValue = 1;
sty = xsltParseStylesheetFile((const xmlChar *)[styleSheetPath cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
doc = xmlParseMemory([xmlMem bytes], [xmlMem length]);
res = xsltApplyStylesheet(sty, doc, nil);
xmlChar* xmlResultBuffer = nil;
xsltSaveResultToString(&xmlResultBuffer, &length, res, sty);
NSString* resultHTML = [NSString stringWithCString: (char *)xmlResultBuffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Result: %@", resultHTML);
```

Result: `<div>a<b<div>`

The result is not an encoded html. Could anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: What happens if `NSString *xml = @"<div>a&amp;lt;b</div>"`?

Comment: @MathiasMüller - ya i have changed & to &amp; and its working..

Comment: I have added this as an answer, then, with an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following: In the course of parsing a string of XML, any entity references are expanded, that is, replaced with the string value they reference.

If your input XML contains entities such as `&lt;`, they will appear as `<` as soon as they are parsed - and before the XML can be processed.

To avoid this, just replace `&` with its entity, too, that is, `&amp;`. Change

```
NSString *xml = @"<div>a&lt;b</div>"
```

to

```
NSString *xml = @"<div>a&amp;lt;b</div>"
```

Then, `&amp;lt;` is resolved to `&lt;` but no further replacement is applied, since it is not an iterative process.